# Order Adjusters in Commerce 2

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce2

In Craft Commerce 1, there is documentation on how to re-order adjustments that do similar things.
https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v1/adjusters.html#ordering-adjustments

But I don't see any similar documentation for how to do that in Commerce 2.

I have 2 plugins that make adjustments to the Sale price and then Order total, but if run in the wrong order, it doesn't work.

Simple solution is to uninstall the plugins and install them in the correct sequence, but was wondering if there was still a way to force them to run in a certain order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `\craft\commerce\services\OrderAdjustments` you should be able to change the ordering of your adjustments by using the `\craft\commerce\services\OrderAdjustments::EVENT_REGISTER_ORDER_ADJUSTERS` event.

```php
use craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent;
use craft\commerce\services\OrderAdjustments;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    OrderAdjustments::class,
    OrderAdjustments::EVENT_REGISTER_ORDER_ADJUSTERS,
    function (RegisterComponentTypesEvent $e) {
        $e->types = [
            // Add the adjusters in whatever order you want here. Leaving this empty would disable all adjusters.
        ];
    }
);
```

Comment: So I'm using the Verbb Gift Voucher plugin in conjunction with my custom one. You're saying when I register my Adjuster, it should look something like:
`$event->types = [
                
                GiftVoucherAdjuster::class, CartAdjustmentsAdjuster::class
            ];`

Comment: Actually, I need the Gift Vouchers Adjuster to run before my CartAdjustementAdjuster. Doing this in my plugin, then disabling and enabling the 2 plugins again doesn't seem to work. Do I have to uninstall and install again? Then I'm back to square one and just easier to install in the correct order.

Comment: finally figured out that I had to add `use verbb\giftvoucher\adjusters\GiftVoucherAdjuster;` at the top of the file. Now I can use the code as @Maarten mentioned. It ends up looking like `$event->types = [
                    CartAdjustmentsAdjuster::class,
                    GiftVoucherAdjuster::class
                ];`

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Marc!